# Checkstyle custom import order

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

I tested our custom checkstyle.xml and tried to set up the import order, here is my code:

```
<module name="CustomImportOrder">
            <property name="customImportOrderRules" value="STATIC###STANDARD_JAVA_PACKAGE###THIRD_PARTY_PACKAGE"/>
            <property name="thirdPartyPackageRegExp" value="^(org|net|com)\."/>
            <property name="standardPackageRegExp" value="^(java|javax)\."/>
            <property name="sortImportsInGroupAlphabetically" value="true"/>
            <property name="separateLineBetweenGroups" value="true"/>
</module>
```

now in my code i have 3 imports:

```
import java.util.List;

import com.rs.ws.config.ApplicationSettings;
import com.rs.ws.config.ApplicationSettingsRegistry;
```

when I ran 'mvn clean test' it complained about checkstyle violation:

```
CustomImportOrder: Import statement for 'java.util.List' is in the wrong order. Should be in the 'STANDARD_JAVA_PACKAGE' group, expecting not assigned imports on this line.
```

I kept adding more line or reducing line between import for java.util and com.rs.ws, it still threw the same complaint. is that because checkstyle expects Static import yet there is no static import in the code so that checkstyle thinks java.util.List was in the Static import spot? how can I fix it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your violations with checkstyle 8.12 CLI.